# The ideal connection implementation for an internet cafe software

Tags: c#

I am coding an internet cafe program and trying to decide which path to take. I've read some articles and came to know that there are a few ways to implement a server/client connection.(a bit messy Asyncronous, simple TCP and Socket) I'm a bit confused. I kindly ask you to show me the ideal way regarding to the needs that I mentioned below

Clients will always stay connected to server and server will know when any client is disconnected. Server will send object and string to clients, clients will send string to server.

So, Should I use an asyncronous or simple tcp or what? Thanks in advance

Comment: The title does describe the problem. Also you need to explain what you are trying to achieve. At least I cant work it out.

Comment: Why all the down votes? He asked a simple architectural question...

Comment: I will +1 your question if you make the title more descriptive.

Comment: My first comment should say "title does not describe the problem". That's my main reason for the down vote. A possible title is "What network setup should I use for an Internet Cafe".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)?

Comment: Thanks. Let me have a look at it. But before digging in to it, Does WCF automatically select the appropriate way for connection or do I still have to choose between tcp, socket and asyncronous?

Comment: I have not used WCF so far but if i remember right you have to setup the communication protocol, i don't know if you can setup multiple and use the "fastest"..

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few good tutorials out there to help you get started on this.

It sounds like you have the basic functionality in mind, so take a look at this tutorial - hopefully it can help you out.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/tcpclientserver.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also you can look this site for basic requirements
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharp/Network/CatalogNetwork.htm